# error Git after download. how do I remove file that cant be delete or move?

Tags: file, download, recycle-bin

I download a file from http://msysgit.github.io/. The file got on to my harddrive without any problem. But now I can't move it, delete it, or even do anything with it. It seem like it crash right on the spot. How do I remove it from my pc?

First I tried moving the file and it did nothing. It just sit there a 0%. So I try stopping it. It didn't work. I relog in to my window. Than I try delete it. Same problem as before. I right click on file and than I click on properties. Nothing has happened.

Answer (score 0):

From here: [this manual page](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html) To power through you might need to open the command prompt as an administrator. I do that by clicking on Start, then in the "run" box I type "cmd". You will see cmd.exe show up. Right-click on it and choose run as administrator.

Here is the command to force delete a file that is read-only:

```
DEL /F C:\examples\MyFile.txt
```

Here is another interesting quote from that page:

> **Undeletable Files**
>
> Files are sometimes created with the very long filenames or reserved
>   names: CON, AUX, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, PRN, NUL 
>   To delete these use the syntax: DEL \.\C:\somedir\LPT1 Alternatively
>   SUBST a drive letter to the folder containing the file.
>
> If a file (or folder) still appears to be 'undeletable' this is often
>   caused by the indexing service. Stopping the service will often enable
>   the file to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. I used `cmd` and did a force delete. For other who have this problem:

1. Force delete using Windows

Enter the command prompt (Start-> Run-> Cmd). use cd 
/d {path to folder}. than do enter ‘del {filename}’. Give it about 5min or less...

Comment: You should accept one of the answers by clicking on the green tick. You can accept your own answer if you wish. This is  how Stack Overflow works as explained in the [tour] and [help]. You gain reputation points by doing these activities.